# Facebook pixel setup via GTM on a SPA(React) fires page view event twice

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

So like the title says, I'm using Google Tag Manager to send events to Facebook. Most events seem fine any only fire once, except the view page event. The event is setup to trigger using GTM's history trigger because we're using React for our site.

Originally it was setup to fire on all history changes, but I notice when using preview mode in GTM that there were two history changes being fired.
1: gtm.historyChange
2: gtm.history change-v2

So, I updated the trigger to only fire on `some changes` and set: `Event equals gtm.historyChange` With this change I now only see one history change in GTM preview mode, but I still see two in the fb pixel helper chrome extension. One Page event has the an event ID and params I want to see, the other has nothing.

I'm no analytics or pixel expert so even pointing to a possible reason why this is happening would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Facebook pixel already considers history change as a page view, so you are double counting it by also triggering it on the history change. Just load it on page view only and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).